# In Freemarker, how to translate each string in a list individually, then join the result

Tags: freemarker

My model contains a list of two-letter language codes, eg (pseudo-code):

```
${info.languages} = [en, jp, mi]
```

I currently have mark-up in my template that formats these as a semicolon-space-separated list:

```
<#if info.languages??>
  ${info.languages?join("; ", "")}
</#if>
```

which gives

> en; jp; mi

I'd like to show the English name for each language code in the semicolon-separated list instead. I know I can use [Locale#getDisplayLanguage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage--) to do the lookup in Java, so I'm not worried about the actual translation part.

My question is how to tie this into the template while still taking advantage of the `join` built-in. I guess ideally I'd want to be able to chain the operators like so:

```
${info.languages?displayLanguage?join(", ", "")}
```

but [it appears](http://freemarker.624813.n4.nabble.com/How-to-add-custom-method-using-built-in-like-syntax-td3081132.html) that the `?xyz` syntax is reserved for core built-ins.

**Tl;dr:** Is there any way to combine a custom function with the `join` built-in? Or something else useful that I'm overlooking? Or is my only choice to have my custom function do the joining as well as the translation?

Comment: I don't believe this complexity belongs in the view layer. Why not do it earlier and keep the view layer relatively stupid?

Comment: That's a good point Dave and I'll have another look at the bigger picture / overall architecture of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions on where this sort of processing belongs aside, I figured out how to do what I described in my question.

In order to still use the `?join` operator (since it really *is* the most common case in terms of joining the values in the list), just make sure the custom method returns a **list** of display names for the languages codes that were passed in.

The following works, assuming that the argument passed in is always a list:

```
public class DisplayLanguageMethod implements TemplateMethodModelEx {
  @Override
  public Object exec(List arguments) throws TemplateModelException {
      if (arguments == null || arguments.isEmpty()) {
          return null;
      }

      Object argObject = arguments.get(0);
      if (argObject == null || !(argObject instanceof TemplateSequenceModel)) {
          return Collections.emptyList();
      }

      TemplateSequenceModel argSequence = ((TemplateSequenceModel) argObject);
      List<String> displayLanguages = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < argSequence.size(); i++) {
          String languageCode = Objects.toString(argSequence.get(i), null);
          String displayName = languageCode;
          if (languageCode != null) {
              Locale argLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag(languageCode);
              if (argLocale != null) {
                  displayName = argLocale.getDisplayName(Locale.getDefault());
              }
          }
          displayLanguages.add(displayName);
      }
      return displayLanguages;
  }
}
```

placed into the context like this:

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("displayLanguage", new DisplayLanguageMethod());
// get template, output writer etc as per usual
template.process(data, writer);
```

and then used in the template like so:

```
<#if info.languages??>
  ${displayLanguage(info.languages)?join("; ", "")}
</#if>
```

Answer (score 1):

`?join` pretty much only exists for convenience, to address the most common case. In more generic cases you should use `#list`. For example:

```
<#list info.languages as lang>${my.displayLanguage(lang)}<#sep>, <#/list>
```

Of course if you do this on multiple places, you should probably move this snippet into a macro.

As of the `?xyz` thing (they are called built-ins), yes, it's reserved for the template language.